# Error when using static member constexpr function in variadic expansion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

I have found some code that seems like a bug in the VC++15 (Visual Studio 2015). It compiles in both GCC and clang, but not VC++.

Anyway, the code can say it all (I think, please leave comments!)

```
template<typename T>
struct doThing
{
    static int constexpr getNum() { return 3; };
};

template<int... ints>
struct iAcceptInts
{

};

template<typename... T>
void forwardThis()
{
    iAcceptInts<T::getNum()...> a; // ERROR: there are no parameter packs available to expand   
                                   //AND ERROR: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

}

int main()
{
    forwardThis<doThing<int>, doThing<bool>, doThing<char>>();
}
```

It seems that this should work, especially considering that it compiles in GCC and Clang.

The error message it produces is this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CES, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\ces\main.cpp(59): error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
1>  c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\ces\main.cpp(64): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void forwardThis<doThing<int>,doThing<bool>,doThing<char>>(void)' being compiled
1>c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\ces\main.cpp(59): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

On a side note, it works fine to use a non-member approach like this:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int getNum() { return 3; }

template<typename T>
struct doThing
{
};

template<int... ints>
struct iAcceptInts
{

};

template<typename... T>
void forwardThis()
{
    iAcceptInts<getNum<T>()...> a;
}

int main()
{
    forwardThis<doThing<int>, doThing<bool>, doThing<char>>();
}
```

[Here's the exact same code running like a champ on GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13114b5a53576031)

So what do you guys think? Compiler bug? Or is it not an advertised feature at all? Or is MSVC correct to reject it?

Comment: This works as a workaround:  `static constexpr int value = getNum();`, then use `T::value`

Comment: And this also works: `iAcceptInts<(T::getNum())...>` - seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the input. I'll head back to my least favorite place in the world: MCFT feedback site!

Comment: In my experience, they've been very nice about explaining when a bug report isn't a bug but actually in compliance with the standard. Worst that can happen is a WONTFIX :)

Comment: No, the peole are fine, I've just had problems with the site. Apparently the last issue I posted I accidentally posted 5 times.

Comment: For those who are interested, here is the issue on MCFT's site: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1913695

Comment: @melak47 thank you so much for your help. Also, thanks for putting your workaround on the page. I know this kind of comment is discouraged, but I thought what you did was above and beyond,  considering you posted your workaround twice.